# What happens to a lead when the triggered webhook call is unsuccessful?

Tags: webhooks, marketo

I have a Marketo Smart Campaign which has a Webhook that submits a lead to my external service each time the campaign is triggered (new lead).
Will Marketo re-submit the lead to the external service if it receives anything other than a `HTTP 200` response from my external service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no automated retry logic.  To handle different cases of responses, you would need to have a Webhook is Called trigger to handle particular responses.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any documentation on Marketo's website regarding this information you could point me to?